# java.lang.String cannot be converted to int... not sure what I'm doing wrong

Tags: java, debugging, compiler-errors, syntax-error

This is my second week in a Java course, so bear with me. I am trying to make a program that allows for a user input of "rock","paper", or "scissors." I am sure there are more efficient ways than what I have done, and I thought I was actually making progress, but now I stuck.

My applicable knowledge to this program is limited to if and if-else statements as well as switch statements. I tried to get a user input for rock, paper, or scissors, convert that to a number, and compare that to a randomly generated number, with 0 representing rock, 1 representing paper, and 2 representing scissors.

```
import java.util.*;

public class RockPaperScissors
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int computer;

       computer = (int)(Math.random() * 2 + 1);

       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

       String player;
       System.out.println("Enter the word rock, paper, or scissors.");
       player = input.next();

    if (computer == 0) {       
           System.out.println("The computer chose rock.");
    }
    else if (computer == 1) {
           System.out.println("The compuer chose paper.");
    }
    else if (computer == 2) {
           System.out.println("The computer chose scissors.");
    }


    // personally starting from here is where I feel like I started to make mistakes.
    int rock = 0;
    int paper = 1;
    int scissors = 2;
    player = (int)player;

       switch (player) {
           case "r" : rock = 0;
           player = 0;
           break;
           case 'p' : paper = 1;
           player = 1;
           break;
           case 's' : scissors = 2;
           player = 2;
           break;
           default : System.out.println("Invalid input");
    }

    if (player == computer) {
          System.out.println("You tied") ;     
        }
    else if (player = 1 && computer = 0 ^ player = 2 && computer = 0) {
        System.out.println("You won");
        }
    else {
        System.out.println("You lost");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you casting a string to an integer?! `player` is a string!

Comment: @AndrewLi, he's making it complicated it lol. he could just use the integer to do the calculation and return it as string in a case

Comment: You don't understand a fundamental idea. You can't store Strings (a reference type) and ints (a primitive) in the same variable! Java is strongly-typed, which means `player` can't store a string and an integer! Also double quotes are for strings and single quotes are for chars!

Comment: Also, your else if uses =... use `==` for comparison...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting String to Int in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java)

Comment: `player = (int)player;` this is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can use `Integer.parseInt()` to convert a String to int.

1. `Integer.parseInt()` Examples
   Example to convert a String “10” to an primitive int.

   ```
   String number = "10";

   int result = Integer.parseInt(number);

   System.out.println(result);
   ```

Output

```
10
```

2.

`Integer.valueOf()` 
Examples
Alternatively, you can use `Integer.valueOf()`, it will returns an Integer object.

```
String number = "10";
Integer result = Integer.valueOf(number);
System.out.println(result);
```

Output

```
10
```

Note

In summary, `parseInt(String)` returns a primitive int, whereas `valueOf(String)` returns a `new Integer()` object.

Comment: But the whole premise of converting a String to an int is just wrong! Look in the switch statement - they are trying to test if a *string* equals *another string*! Why convert to an integer in the first place...? The **real** problem here is that they are attempting to use `player` for more than it should be. They are trying to store integers and strings in the same variable.

Comment: @AndrewLi, true. If it's me i'll use the equal() function but i'm just providing the answer based on his header title.

Comment: It really doesn't matter what's in the title. An answer must address all the problems, and there a few major ones that this answer does not address.